# When none exists in ways that are entirely relatable

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, complex-sentences

I can't get the meaning of this sentence, from the book *Same as Ever* by Morgan Houseland.

> You'd find people seeking the secret to a happy life and trying to find certainty when none exists in ways that are entirely relatable.

I see the meaning like this: People are trying to find the secret and certainty but these two (secret and certainty) can't even be described.

Is it right translation of the idea?

The more surrounding text for better context:

> History is filled with surprises no one could have seen coming. But
> it's also filled with so much timeless wisdom.
>
> If you traveled in time to five hundred years ago or five hundred
> years from now, you would be astounded at how much technology and
> medicine has changed. The geopolitical order would make no sense to
> you. The language and dialect might be completely foreign.
>
> But you'd notice people falling for greed and fear just like they do
> in our current world.
>
> You'd see people persuaded by risk, jealousy, and tribal affiliations
> in ways that are familiar to you.
>
> You'd see overconfidence and shortsightedness that remind you of
> people's behavior today.
>
> **You'd find people seeking the secret to a happy life and trying to**
> **find certainty when none exists in ways that are entirely relatable.**
>
> When transported to an unfamiliar world, you'd spend a few minutes
> watching people behave and say, “Ah. I've seen this before. Same as
> ever.”
>
> Change captures our attention because it's surprising and exciting.
> But the behaviors that never change are history's most powerful
> lessons, because they preview what to expect in the future. Your
> future. Everyone's future. No matter who you are, where you're from,
> how old you are, or how much money you make, there are timeless
> lessons from human behavior that are some of the most important things
> you can ever learn.

Comment: Can you please provide more of the surrounding text for better context.

Comment: *"...in ways that are entirely relatable"* translates to "...as we all know." We all want happiness and certainty in our lives. The phrase "where none exists" belongs to the first part of the sentence. It would be clearer with a comma after 'exists'.

Comment: @dubious , I've added surrounding text.

Comment: The next sentence added seems to confirm my explanation. *“Ah. I've seen this before. Same as ever.”*

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you very much. Can you give me a key for understanding why "in ways that are entirely relatable" translate to "as we all know" I just don't know how I should looking for information to get this meaning.

Comment: *"in ways that are entirely relatable"* ... "in ways we understand". The text seems to be written in therapy-speak. "I can relate to what you say" means "I understand".

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh I see. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

The antecedent of **none** is **certainty**.  The antecedent wouldn't include "the secret to a happy life" as well. But I suspect the author meant to refer to both and should have written "when *neither* exists".

I suppose "entirely relatable" is synonymous with "very familiar".  The same old human frailties would be recognizable despite the five centuries separating us from them.

Comment: Perhaps note too that "in ways that are entirely relatable" modifies *seeking* and *trying.*

Comment: Yes, "in ways..." is a PP  that describes their actions, their seeking and trying .

Answer (score 0):

> If you traveled in time to five hundred years ago or five hundred
> years from now . . . You’d find people seeking . . . and
> trying to find . . . in ways that are entirely
> relatable.

*In ways that are entirely relatable* means *in ways that you can fully relate to*, which means *in ways that you can totally understand based on your own experience*.

> **relatable** *adjective*
> **3.** That can be related to (*relate* *v*. 9); with which one can identify or empathize.
>
> **relate** *verb*
> **9.** *intransitive*. With *to*. To understand or have empathy for; to identify or feel a connection with.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*(https://oed.com/) (login
> required)</sub>